# Split a scipy.sparse matrix into train and test

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

```
sc_f = sc27.tocsr()
X, y = sc_f
X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sc_f, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3)
```

I was getting error while splitting the sparse matrix to a Train and Test.
How to split the array into train and test?

sc_f: scipy sparse matrix

I want to split it in such a way so that in y I have the target i.e 'is_true' which I want to predict and it takes only two values 0 and 1. 
When I'm converting my scipy sparse matrix to sparseDataFrame. I'm not able to access it as df['is_true'] where df is the sparseDataFrame. How do I split it. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to describe the error.  We can't guess.  Also make sure that `train_test_split` can work with sparse matrix, and if so, are there any restrictions.  Any questions about `sparseDateFrame` belong in another question.

Comment: I wan to split my Sparse Matrix such that X = np.array(sc_f), y = np.array(sc_f['is_true']). Is there some way to split in such a way a sparse matrix? I want my target 'y' to contain 'is_true'. Can you tell how to do this?

Comment: What is `X, y = sc_f` supposed to do?  With my examples that produces an error.  The `x['is_true']` expression only makes sense is `x` is a dictionary (or a few other objects that take a string index).  That certainly doesn't apply to `csr` sparse matrices.  `arr = sc_f.toarray()` will create a dense `ndarray` that might be easier to work with, at least at the learning stage.  Also read [mcve]

Comment: While converting to dense matrix getting a memory error.

Comment: If you get a memory error, that isn't a minimal example.